# How to add jquery dependency to jquery.zoom for porto theme js under app/design

Tags: magento2, requirejs, porto-theme

The website Magento is 2.1.7. We built a customised theme based on Porto theme.
Now our frontend product page has an exception:

```
pub/static/frontend/vendor/theme-name/en_AU/Magento_Catalog/js/jquery.zoom.min.js:23 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'zoom' of undefined
```

The code at line 23 is:

```
$.zoom = function(target, source, img, magnify) { ...
```

I think the exception is due to jquery.zoom is loaded before jquery so that $ is undefined. So I think I should find or create a requirejs-config file somewhere to create this dependency.

**My question** is: How to cite jquery.zoom.min.js in requirejs-config.js correctly? The location of jquery.zoom is

```
design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_catalog/jquery.zoom.min.js
```

I tried to call it **Magento_Catalog/js/jquery.zoom.min** in requirejs-config.js, but it seems requirejs cannot locate the file. Here is how I did exactly:

I add the dependency in `design/frontend/vendor/theme-name/requirejs-config.js, the file is like:`

```
var config = {
shim: {
    jquery: {
        exports: '$'
    },
    'Smartwave_Megamenu/js/sw_megamenu':
        {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }, ...
```

I tried to add jquery.zoom dependency here like:

```
        'Magento_Catalog/js/jquery.zoom.min':
        {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
```

I call it *Magento_Catalog/js/jquery.zoom.min* because I found the deployed jquery.zoom.min.js is at

```
pub/static/frontend/vendor/theme-name/en_AU/Magento_Catalog/js/jquery.zoom.min.js
```

Then in the merged requirejs-config.js at

```
pub/static/_requirejs/frontend/vendor/theme-name/en_US/requirejs-config.js
```

I can see the dependency has been created successfully, but the exception is still there so I guess magento cannot find jquery.zoom.min.js file by *Magento_Catalog/js/jquery.zoom.min*. So what should I call/cite it in requirejs-config.js?

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48394872/zoom-is-not-function-in-porto-magento-2-demo-1-theme

Comment: It works. Thanks for that very much, I didn't find that post. So I think what the solution did is it removed zoom.js from the product page view, and then loads it for all views? Maybe that is the only solution we can do because of the location of this zoom.js. Thank you @magefms!

Comment: That's great. I think you can add it as an answer and mark it as accepted so it can help others who might run into the same issue in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for @magefms provide the solution.
[please find the solution in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48394872/zoom-is-not-function-in-porto-magento-2-demo-1-theme)
In a nutshell, it removed jquery.zoom.js from the product page view, and then loads it for all views by creating the dependency in requirejs-config.js.

It may not be a perfect solution because now all pages will load jquery.zoom.js, but it did work.

Answer (score 0):

**Your question**:
Is the location of jquery.zoom is design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_catalog/jquery.zoom.min.js

**Ans:**
Location of jquery.zoom For Proto Theme (i.e YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto)

YOUR-MAGENTO-***ROOT/app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Catalog/web/js/view/product/view/jquery.zoom.min.js***

** Note:** 
Proto Theme adds dependencies in design/frontend/vendor/theme-name/requirejs-config.js for sw_megamenu because
sw_megamenu.js file may not be coded as per AMD structure, So dependencies of Jquery has mentioned in requirejs-config but jquery.zoom.min.js may be written as per AMD structure. So  you may not need to specify Jquery  dependencies for this zoom module

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry I don't think I expressed my question clearly. I know where the jquery.zoom.min.js is, but I don't know how to cite it in requirejs-config.js. I tried to call it **Magento_Catalog/js/jquery.zoom.min** in requirejs-config.js, but it seems requirejs cannot locate the file, so the dependency cannot be created properly